# Can a random number sampling return the same result infinitely many times in a row?

Tags: sampling

Say we are sampling a standard normal distribution (a gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1), repeatedly. Do the following statements make sense and are they correct?

- The probability that we get the number 4, n times in a row is 1 for any finite n.
- The probability that we get the number 4 infinity many times in a row is 0.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: What is a "standard distribution"? Can you think of any distributions for which your two bullet points would be correct, or wrong? Hint: consider degenerate distributions.

Comment: [Dilbert gave an illustration](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) of the issue

Comment: @StephanKolassa standard as in gaussian with mean 0 and variance 1. It's not for a course, I made the first claim when I was explaining random sampling once but then I realized I'm not fully certain if it's true or if so if it's a strong claim.

Comment: @Henry yea exactly what I was thinking when I  asked this. lol

Comment: For an [absolutely continuous probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) like the Gaussian, the probability of getting *any* particular value, whether $4$, $17$ or $-\frac{17}{53}$, is zero. So your first statement is false already for $n=1$, and your second statement is true even if you replace "infinitely many times in a row" by "once".

Comment: Use the axioms of probability and any definition of standard Normal you like to demonstrate (1) the chance of the event $\{4\}$ is less than the chance of the interval $(4-1/N,4+1/N)$ for any $N\gt 0;$ (2) the chance of that interval is less than $1/N;$ and (3) the chance of obtaining a sequence of $n$ values from that interval is therefore less than $1/N^n.$  Letting $N$ and then $n$ grow arbitrarily large answers all your questions.